# How to use Liquid to filter on text

Tags: filter, shopify, liquid

I have a metafile that contains text like:

```
[Title] 
body text
```

I want to use filter to show only text between the brackets as title and the same metefied for body text only, please help~

{{ details | filters }}

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution but I don't know if it's the best one

To show only text between brackets []

```js
{{ details_01 | remove: '['| split: "]" | slice: 0, 1 }}
```

To show the body text.

```js
{{ details_01 | remove: '['| split: "]" | slice: 1, 1 }}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. I couldn't think of any better one.